# Angular-1. Как правильно прокручивать элементы в цикле?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Коллеги, есть такой пример для наглядности

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.li-example')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', function() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.li-example')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
      arr[i].classList.remove('li-example-active');
    })
    arr[i].classList.add('li-example-active');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
li.li-example-active{
  background-color: #00c;
}
```

```html
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
</menu>
```

Не думаю, что надо объяснять, что в примере выше происходит.

---

---

---

Меня интересует, как сделать такое же в `*Angular-1*`

Мои попытки...

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myExample = ['Example-1', 'Example-2', 'Example-3', 'Example-4', 'Example-5'];
    }
  }
});

app.directive('liExample', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      //element.addClass('li-example-active'); Почему данный вариант **JQUERY** за пределами цикла forEach работает
      angular.forEach(element, i => {
        scope.functionClick = function() {
          i.classList.add('li-example-active'); // хотя прекрасно работает класический вариант js добавления и удаления *class*
          //i.addClass('li-example-active');// а в цикле не работает
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

li.li-example-active {
  background-color: #00c;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-repeat="example in myExample" ng-click="functionClick()"><span>{{example}}</span></li>
</menu>
<html>
```

И как в данном варианте реализовать этот пример как в первом классическом варианте JS???? Чтобы элемент по которому кликнули присваивался класс `li-example-active`, а  остальных удалялся класс `li-example-active`???

И отдельно хочу спросить правильно ли я понял, что `angular.forEach(element, i => {})`, аргументов не три `Array.forEach((s, i, arr) => {})`` как в классическом варианте js, а один ?

---

---

---

И еще один вариант подобного примера с другой реализацией по которому тоже есть вопросы

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myExample = ['Example-1', 'Example-2', 'Example-3', 'Example-4', 'Example-5'];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

li.li-example-active {
  background-color: #00c;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-repeat="example in myExample" ng-click="active = !active" ng-class="active ? '' : 'li-example-active'"><span>{{example}}</span></li>
</menu>
<html>
```

Вопрос тот же... И как в данном варианте реализовать этот пример как в первом классическом варианте JS????

---

---

---

А этот пример не очень важен, так просто, для общего развития....

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

li.li-example span {
  background-color: green;
}

li.li-example span.span-active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-click="active = !active"><span ng-class="active ? '' : 'span-active'">Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example" ng-click="active = !active"><span ng-class="active ? '' : 'span-active'">Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example" ng-click="active = !active"><span ng-class="active ? '' : 'span-active'">Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example" ng-click="active = !active"><span ng-class="active ? '' : 'span-active'">Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example" ng-click="active = !active"><span ng-class="active ? '' : 'span-active'">Example</span></li>

</menu>
<html>
```

Вопрос.... Почему в данном варианте без `ng-repeat` `class="span-active"` получают все элементы `Span`, а не тот по родителю которого кликнули....

Comment: слишком много вопросов в одном, я тут вижу как минимум 2-3 дубликата.

Comment: @Grundy, согласен, что много, хотя бы на один получить ответ...

Comment: `active` берется из `scope`, так как в нем такого поля нет - значение будет `undefined`, выражение `undefined ? '' : 'span-active'` даст `'span-active'` поэтому все элементы имеют этот класс

Comment: @Grundy, я правильно понял, что твой последний коммент о втором варианте?  Если да, то будь другом,  покажи наглядный пример, у меня не получилось реализовать....

Comment: это ответ на  _Вопрос.... Почему в данном варианте без ng-repeat class="span-active" получают все элементы Span, а не тот по родителю которого кликнули...._

Comment: @Grundy, ок понял...

Comment: чтобы понять почему не работает, посмотри справку по scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с ангуляром, лучше исходить от данных, а не от разметки.

Проблема в данном случае заключается в том, что со стороны данных есть только массив и никак не определяется что именно выбрано, из-за этого идет попытка вычислить это с помощью DOM элементов. Вместо этого достаточно было добавить поле `selected` и сохранять в него индекс выбранного элемента. Далее в `ng-repeat` просто проверять текущий `index` и выбранный и если они совпадают выставлять класс. Для этого достаточно стандартной директивы `ng-class`.

В итоге получается следующий код:

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myExample = ['Example-1', 'Example-2', 'Example-3', 'Example-4', 'Example-5'];
      scope.selected = 0;
      scope.functionClick = function(index) {
        scope.selected = index;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

li.li-example-active {
  background-color: #00c;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-class="{'li-example-active':selected==$index}" ng-repeat="example in myExample" ng-click="functionClick($index)"><span>{{example}}</span></li>
</menu>
<html>
```

---

```
//element.addClass('li-example-active'); Почему данный вариант **JQUERY** за пределами цикла forEach работает
// потому что `element` - это jqLite объект, а следовательно у него есть все необходимые методы
angular.forEach(element, i => {
    scope.functionClick = function() {
      i.classList.add('li-example-active'); // хотя прекрасно работает класический вариант js добавления и удаления *class*
      //i.addClass('li-example-active');// а в цикле не работает
      // потому что как и в любом другом обходчике в callback передается **HTMLElement** а не jqLite обертка.
```

---

> правильно ли я понял, что angular.forEach(element, i => {}), аргументов не три `Array.forEach((s, i, arr) => {})`` как в классическом варианте js, а один ?

Нет не правильно. Точное определение можно увидеть в [справке](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

> The `iterator` function is invoked with `iterator(value, key, obj)`

---

> И еще один вариант подобного примера с другой реализацией по которому тоже есть вопросы

Проблема со скопом: `ng-repeat`- создает свой скоп, следовательно на каждой итерации у каждого элемента свое свойство `active`, поэтому они меняются независимо друг от друга.

---

> А этот пример не очень важен

Ошибка обратная предыдущей: так как для каждого элемента нет отдельного скопа, `active` - один на все элементы, что и сказывается на результате.

Comment: @Air, в примере же именно так и есть?